# No Package C-states (powertop) Dell XPS 15 9570

Tags: dell, power-management, intel, powertop

I recently made the switch from Windows to Linux after the discrete graphics chip (nVidia 1050Ti) died.

The overall experience is very pleasant as Linux is highly customizable, snapy and less resource intensive compared to Windows (3-4GB of Ram usage while using Firefox is unheard of as windows used about 3-4gb on idle with no apps running) . My main issue is that Battery life on linux has been a nightmare for me as I'm getting around 5hrs on a laptop that easily did 8-9h on windows. I have already installed power management and apps like powertop and TLP and the [Respin Script made by JackHack96](https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin) these tweaks did help but not by much.

Powertop reports around 14-16W of power usage which is abnormaly high for this laptop. The CPU core is for the most part, consuming around 1-2W of power during normal use (Measured using `S-tui` as it is the closest thing I could find to HWinfo on Windows) but the total package power is too high sitting around 5-7W of power during normal use. Since the cores themselves draw only around 1-2W that means that there is something on the processor package that's drawing around 4-5W that aren't the CPU cores. [See my previous post for a bit more detail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255995/ubuntu-20-04-lts-dell-xps-15-9570-high-package-power-consumption-and-high-batte). I have no way of telling what it might be but I think I know what's causing it.

[Powertop reports that the CPU package has no C-States](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hinX.png) which means that the parts of the cpu that aren't just the processing cores aren't being power managed properly (The CPU cores do have C-states) I've had this problem on windows but I was able to fix it with the help of the [XPS 15 9570 Owners Thread](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/xps-15-9570-owners-thread.817008/page-298) but the fix there only applies to Windows.

I would prefer to keep Linux as I've really grown to hate Windows but I will switch back if the battery life on Linux is this bad as I use my laptop on the go a lot.

Any advice or help is much apreciated.

Comment: Hi.```intel_cstate``` should have been shipped with the linux kernel itself. You can check its existence via ```lsmod | grep -i "intel\_cstate"```.I think the problem is somewhere else.Have you monitored the CPU usage while on battery? Maybe some extensions or anything else are in charge of that.

Comment: Please provide: Version of Ubuntu; Processor make and model, `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`; CPU frequency scaling driver, `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`; CPU frequency scaling governor, `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`; Idle driver and governor, `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/*`.